# Excel unusual sequence formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am looking for a formula to generate the sequence down row B starting from B3. I would like the sequence to be: every fourth term +8 and the following three terms to be -1 sequentially, 
ie) **11**,10,9,8,**19**,18,17,16,**27**,26,25,24,**35**,34,33,32....

Any ideas?

I have tried =IF(MOD(B3,4)=0,($B$3:B3)+8,B3-1) however this only works for the first few terms as the add 8 always occurs to B3 rather than to B7, B11... in turn

Comment: You are missing the MAX() from my formula.

Comment: I have tried your formula also many times and still not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just enter

```
=11-MOD(ROW()-3,4)+INT((ROW()-3)/4)*8
```

in `B3` and drag/copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In **B3** enter 11, in **B4** enter:

```
=IF(MOD(B3,4)=0,B3+11,B3-1)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Like Scott said you have to use the following:
In B3 write 11
In B4 write:

```
=IF(MOD($B3,4)=0,Max($B$3:$B3)+8,$B3-1)
```

and drag it down
Mod($B3,4)=0 will occur every fourth term
Max($B$3:$B3) will return the highest value to which you will add 8

[image]

In case you need to start with any value and the sequence is like you said the following 3 values B3-1 and the fourth value B3+8 you can use:
Just start in B3 with the initial value and in B4 write:

```
=IF(MOD(COUNT($B$3:B3),4)=0,MAX($B$3:$B3)+8,$B3-1)
```

and drag it down
Mod(Count(),4)=0 will correspond to the following value + 8